# Enabling Migrations for the test database

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In EF4 winforms, I have a solution with Datalayer, DomainClasses, UI and Test projects.
The test project uses a different database than the main project.

I have the main connection string set up with a connection string name in the UI's app.config.
I have the test connection string set up in the Test project's app.config with the same connection string name.

My context is set up to use the connection string name as follows:

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("EFTest")    // uses named connection string from app.config
    {  }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

I can enable migrations in the datalayer project. However when I try enabling projects in the test project I get an error:

```
 PM> enable-migrations -ProjectName Test
 No context type was found in the assembly 'Test'.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to enable migrations in the project that contains your `DbContext`. If the Test project does not contain a `DbContext`, you don't need to enable it for migrations.

**Detail**:

You have not specified exactly, but it sounds like you are only using a single `DbContext`, and that it is in the DataLayer project. The `Enable-Migrations` command simply creates the scaffold structure needed to let you specify migrations themselves. A migration is the single named class that contains the set of commands that should be run to upgrade to and downgrade from a database version, regardless of which database (test/live/dev) you run it on. Therefore, you only need to run `Enable-Migrations` for the datalayer project, using

```
> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName DataLayer
```

These commands are stored in the `DbContext`'s project, and are generated by comparing the classes that your `DbContext` references in properties such as `public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }` against a database structure (as well as other things such as Fluent API code). You will most likely therefore want to specifically generate these by comparing to your test (or maybe even a development) database, not the live database, to do this you do:

```
> Add-Migration -ProjectName DataLayer -StartUpProjectName Test
```

Once you have done this, you can run the commands to migrate specifically your live or test database using:

```
> Update-Database -ProjectName DataLayer -StartUpProjectName [Test|UI]
```

As always, `> get-help Enable-Migrations` (or `get-help` for any of the migrations command) lists all the configuration switches and what they do for you.